# Facebook Embedded Post só é permitida para perfis que permitem Seguidores Públicos?

Tags: javascript, facebook

Fiz uma aplicação simples para testar a capacidade de incorporar publicações em sites externos do Facebook. Nela, você cola uma URL de qualquer post do Facebook, clica um botão e o post é inserido em uma `div`.

Separei alguns links e comecei a bateria de testes. Evidentemente, tomei o cuidado de separar somente posts públicos. A grande surpresa foi que grande parte destes links, mesmo sendo públicos, gerou um aviso que o conteúdo fora removido ou desrespeita as leis de privacidade.

A maior surpresa foi quando eu colei um link de um post do meu próprio perfil e a mesma mensagem foi gerada. Pesquisei nas configurações do perfil e vi que tudo estava completamente liberado para todos os públicos, porém, eu não havia configurado a opção *Quem pode me seguir* para *Todos* (estava *Amigos*). Quando eu mudei esta configuração, o aplicativo funcionou com todos os meus links.

O problema é que esta opção, por padrão, é somente para *amigos*, o que limita grandiosamente as possibilidades de incorporar os posts.

Curiosamente, na documentação do próprio [facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/search/?q=public+posts), as informações sobre quais os requisitos para que um post possa ser incorporado em outra página são:

1. Deve ser um post público
2. Deve ser de alguém que você está seguindo
3. Todos os seus amigos são seguidos automaticamente

Existe alguma configuração especial para resolver esta questão?

Answer (score 1):

Se sua pergunta é uma configuração no código a ser posto em site externo para forçar carregar o conteúdo, ela não existe. Caso contrário não teria razão pra por algo que as pessoas iria sempre por por padrão. Esse tipo de nível de permissão tem que ser definido no proprio Facebook mesmo.

O que você pode fazer é ir em todos os post e alterar para público. Algo que tenho quase certeza que também tem é uma configuração específica que altera qual permissão padrão para cada nova postagem, e nela você poderia alterar para 'publico', de modo que apenas não precise alterar o padrão da próxima vez.

Nota: perfis de pessoas menores de 18 anos automaticamente não permitem postagens definidas como público. Esse outro problema pode afetar algumas pessoas, então é bom saber que existe.

### Fazer sugestão para mudar o comportamento do Facebook

**Como o que você quer é diferente da polícica de privacidade do Facebook, e da forma atual não tem como ser feito, recomendo que de feedback sobre a ferramenta no link apropriado em** https://www.facebook.com/help/127103474099499/. Escolha qual seu produto e escreva em detalhes o porque isso seria melhor.

Comment: Emerson, o problema é que não basta somente ser público, você tem que permitir os tais seguidores "não amigos". Eu preciso mostrar somente os posts públicos de um grupo de amigos, numa página própria. Seria bastante improdutivo ter que pedir para cada um deles permitir seguidores anônimos, concorda?

Comment: Segui sua orientação e enviei as minhas sugestões e aproveitei para ler o FAQ sobre o assunto. Encontrei algumas informações que contrariam a minha experiência. Estou alterando a pergunta para ver se mais alguém passou pelo mesmo problema.